# Can we say that $\infty * 0 = 0$?

Tags: calculus

Because I wanted to say that if
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$$
And 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$$
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n=0$$

Comment: There's one place in math, where $0\cdot\infty=0$, but this isn't it.

Comment: Take, for example $f(x)=x^{100},g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Then $\lim x \to 0 $would be$ 0*\infty$, with real result 0.

Comment: *Can we say that $\infty\cdot0=0$ ?* - [Yes, we can](http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/108/4/a/yes_we_can_by_balddog4-d4wlr19.jpg) ! But would we also be *right* ? Probably not... ;-$)$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't true. Take $a_n=n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: So when can I use $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n*\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$

Comment: You can do that when both limits exist and are not equal to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: You can do that as long as the product is not indeterminate, like $0*\infty$

Comment: When $\lim_n a_n$ and $\lim_n b_n$ are both finite, or one infinite and the other not null.

Comment: @Sebastien So can I do it with one of them being infinite but not when both? and I have to make sure that the final product is determinated right?

Comment: Sorry, I've writted to quick... Yes if the both are infinite you can "multiply" them like the intuition say it to do.

Comment: Just my thank you :-) very much.

Answer (score 2):

No, because if
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty \times 0$$
the limit is indeterminate. Use L'Hopital's Rule if you get a result like this.

If you get
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \times g(x) = \infty \times 0$$
write it as
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{g(x)}}$$
and then use L'Hopital's Rule.